# Why can't I write to an environment variable?

Tags: cmd, environment-variables

I am trying to figure out why I get an error when trying to set an environment variable.

I write the following command in a `cmd.exe` shell.

```
set logFile=%time:~0,2%
```

but I keep on getting the following error message

```
Environment variable 13 not defined
```

Can someone assist?

GorovDude

Answer (score 0):

That is really strange. Your code should work. It seems that the batch is ignoring the `logFile=` in your code.

To verify this try:

```
set logFile
```

to see if logFile is indeed not set.

Have you tried typing the code directly into the command prompt?